# Android - Breaking down a Spanned object

Tags: android, spannable, spanned

```
spanned = Html.fromHtml("<sup>aaa</sup>bbb<sub>ccc</sub><b>ddd</b>");
```

Will create a Spanned object with with 3 spans `aaa`, `ccc`, `ddd`.

`bbb` is being ignored since it's not inside an html tag,

```
spans = spanned.getSpans(0, spanned.length(), Object.class);
```

will only identify 3 spans.

I need a way to extract all the 4 sections of the code, if possible into some sort of an array that will allow to me to identify the the type of each span.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need a way to extract all the 4 sections of the code

[Use `nextSpanTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#nextSpanTransition%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29) to find the starting point of the next span. The characters between your initial position (first parameter to `nextSpanTransition()`) and the next span represent an unspanned portion of text.

You can take a look at [the source code to the `toHtml()` method on the `Html` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) to see this in action.

Comment: it's <b> for bold. this breaks down into the correct parts but after getting that the first span is from 0 to 3 how do i get it's type? superscript in my example.

Comment: @Calculator: That will be determined by the type of span object returned by `getSpans()` for the 0-3 range. You will wind up with a lot of `instanceof` checks, I imagine, just as the `toHtml()` code does that I linked you to. BTW, my apologies for misreading your HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

'bbb' is the one which is not inside html tag. Even though i guess it will not be missed. 'ccc' is a subscript, may be it is rendered but not visible to you. Try to increase textview height if you have constrained it.

Comment: sorry, i ment bbb not ccc. the question remains, what do i do to that spanned object to extract all the parts of the data? aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd separately.

Answer (score 0):

use this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String, android.text.Html.ImageGetter, android.text.Html.TagHandler), pass null for ImageGetter and your custom TagHandler

see the example

```
String source = "<b>bold</b> <i>italic</i> <unk>unknown</unk>";
TagHandler tagHandler = new TagHandler() {
    Stack<Integer> starts = new Stack<Integer>();
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
        if (tag.equals("unk")) {
            if (opening) {
                starts.add(output.length());
            } else {
                int start = starts.pop();
                int end = output.length();
                Object what = new Object();
                output.setSpan(what, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }
};
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(source, null, tagHandler);
TextUtils.dumpSpans(spanned, new LogPrinter(Log.DEBUG, TAG), "span ");
```

Comment: same results, 3 spans using Spanned.getSpans();

Comment: Did you add a new span in handleTag when opening == false?